# Drupal 8: REST export view not working with simple_oauth module

Tags: rest, drupal, drupal-views, drupal-8

I am using [Drupal 8.3.x](https://www.drupal.org/download) with [simple_oauth](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_oauth) module for REST authorization and authentication.

I created one simple REST export view and set "Authentication" to "basic_auth, simple_oauth".

But when I try URL it's show me error

```
{
  "message": "The used authentication method is not allowed on this route."
}
```

View Details:

[image]

UPDATE:
Header Details:

```
"url": "http://localhost/d8/api/stories?_format=hal_json",
"method": "GET",
"headers": {
    "authorization": "Bearer <oauth token>"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolve my problem by removing "Authentication" and added "Access" by role type.

[image]